If I only have access to a Node, how can I achieve something like Element.querySelector?
Assume you're not able to access an Element type, only a Node type. (I have this constraint because I'm using inject(ElementRef) in Angular, but there are other cases where it might happen)
A Node instance doesn't have a querySelector method, but it has a childNodes list property, and each of them have their own childNodes, and so on. With these, a searching algo could be implemented to find a desired Node in this Node tree, making up for the absence of querySelector.
My problem is that this seems so obvious that it sounds like it should be a native thing. Does it already exist? Or can I convert the Node to an Element so I can access the native querySelector method?

This is a bit vague. Can you provide a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve as a [mcve]?

FWIW, the querySelector* methods aren't exclusive to the Element type. They're available on all types which extend the ParentNode interface (e.g. Document, etc.)

Note that a node can be of different types, e.g. a text, a comment, an elements attribute, ...
which can't have children, i.e. their childNodes is always empty. - I suppose the way to go is to infer/narrow the type Element somehow, e.g. with a user-defined type guard. If you only need to use querySelector at some point, you can simply check for the existence of the querySelector method, then typescript wouldn't complain.
